# Simulating a click depending on a url parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, select, dropdownbox

I have a parameter which is appended to the url. Depending on the value of this parameter, I need to simulate a click on a dropdownbox item. I tried to use the selected index and it works. However, when using the selected index, it doesn't function like a click and I have some functionality which is only shown when there is a click on the dropdown item.

The URL is something like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html?paramName=paramValue
```

Is there a way in javascript how I can achieve this? I tried the .click() event but to no avail.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code out of the `.click` event handler, and call this new function from both locations (click handler & on URL parsing).

Comment: What do you mean? I need to simulate the click on page load

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the click?

Comment: I have a dropdown, on change of this dropdown, an image is changed. If with JS I handle the URL parameters, and if option2 is passed, I manage to select option2 from the dropdown, but the image won't change accordingly. For the image to change, a click needs to take place

Comment: I seem to recall very inconsistent event firing across browsers when it comes to selecting options. If its important to your purpose, watch out for this.

Comment: I would again suggest to change the code that is handling the image change to be directly called from your URL handling function, as opposed to depend on a `click` event.